# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : Access is denied

Tags: c#, windows, permissions, windows-services, performancecounter

I'm having windows service. I'm using PerformanceCounter class to get CPU Data from Domain Machine.
I'm running my code with Domain Admin privilege.

So problem is here, I'm able to get CPU Data using PerformanceCounter while running code in Visual Studio. However, Same code is not working after installing windows service.

Here's code:

```
PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter();
pc.MachineName = "ws-Rahul";
pc.CategoryName = "Processor";
pc.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
pc.InstanceName = "_Total";

double value = pc.NextValue();
```

Below is exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : {"Access is denied"}
```

Comment: @Amit Sorry It didn't help. I've already seen this answer

Comment: It sounds like whatever user you choose to run the service as needs permission on the target machine to read the counters.

Comment: @mikez User running windows service is having Domain Admin permission. But same service works fine when I run through Visual Studio. Its not working after installing service.

Comment: Services typically run as Network Service or Local System are you saying you've manually changed the service logon after installation? What happens if you try to read the local machine's counters?

Comment: @mikez I didn't changed service logon manually. I'm able to read local machine's counters.

Comment: If you didn't change it, then its probably still network service or local system. To change it right click the service in scm, go to the logon tab, and enter the username and password.

Comment: Hey @mikez Your suggestion worked for me. I just added my user as Service Logon User. Thanks Very Much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services typically run as Network Service or Local System, unless you have configured them overwise. It sounds like you haven't changed the service logon user. You can do it from service control manager by right clicking the service and going to the Logon tab. Or you can do it from the command line:

```
sc config ServiceName obj= Domain\user password= pass
```

Note the space between `obj=` and `Domain\user` it is not a typo. It is required. The same for `password=`.